# Separation of variables, Diff equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I have the equation 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{1+x^2}{x(1+\sin3y)}
$$ 
and I must use separation of variables method to find the general solution but I don't know how to start solving this. Any hints please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A differential equation is separable if you can write it as
$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \mathrm f(x)\cdot\mathrm g(y)$$
If you can then you solve by "getting the $y$s on one side and the $x$s on the other":
$$\frac{1}{\mathrm g(y)}~\mathrm dy = \mathrm f(x)~\mathrm dx$$
Then integrating:
$$\int \frac{1}{\mathrm g(y)}~\mathrm dy = \int \mathrm f(x)~\mathrm dx$$

In your example, you can write
$$\frac{1+x^2}{x(1+\sin 3y)} \equiv \frac{1+x^2}{x}\cdot \frac{1}{1+\sin 3y}$$
You can see what $\mathrm f(x)$ and $\mathrm g(y)$ are, and should be able to continue.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int (1+\sin 3y)dy=\int\left(\frac{1}{x}+x\right)dx$$